# Azure SQL server import export responds with Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClie

Tags: sql-server, azure

Azure SQL server import export responds with Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClie
Not able to see full stacktrace
Demo logs are as below

```
Additional details
Could not import package.
Warning SQL72012: The object [information_9] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
Warning SQL72012: The object [stacktrace] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClie
```

Error logs are incomplete. So, I am not able to identify MSG message number for it.

Please suggest possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The error SQL72014 is requesting to enable contained database authentication on the SQL Server instance.

In order to restore a contained database coming from Azure SQL Database into on-premise SQL Server instance the "contained database authentication" property must be enabled.

***Solution:***

To enable this property please try the below script:

```
sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```